# Data from the database in android is not retrived in proper format

Tags: java, android, database, arraylist, adapter

I am trying an database related application in android in which i have come across a problem. My data is stored in database, but when i try to display it in listview it comes in the format shown in the image. I have a getter and setter class for Task, which is string. My adapter and Arraylist are both of type Task i.e.

ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
ArrayAdapter adapter;

where Task is a class whose constructors are as

```
public Task(int seqNo, String taskStr) {
    this._seqNo = seqNo;
    this._taskStr = taskStr;
}

public Task(String taskStr) {
    this._taskStr = taskStr;
}
```

the data retrieved is given somewhat like this

com.wtd.tasklist.Task@3423423

com.wtd.tasklist.Task@d979999

and so on.

Kindly help. I am really stuck.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code you use to call the database method and how you store the values received. I think u dont use a Cursor

Comment: Yeah antonis, i did use cursor. but in database handler. this was the code from my getter-setter class. the solution to my query is given below by Stanislav. But thanks for your response. have a great day!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Task class you need to override correctly ".toString() method

something like that:

```
class Task {
    ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return _taskStr;
    }
   ...
}
```